# posting one value using ajax (frontend)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, rest

I have a problem with connection frontend-backend. I would like to send one value (radio1Value) from javascript function (on click) using jquery ajax. This function should look like I have wrote?
If yes how should REST look in Java? Should this number that backend have received be in function Get() as a parameter?

```javascript
$.ajax({
    url: "someurl",
    method: "post",
    data: radio1Value

    success: function (response) {
        alert("Success!");
    }
});
```

```java
@GET
@Path("/{ship}")
public int Get(){
    //check in matrix if number from radiovalue exists
}
```

After checking I would like to send response from backend to frontend.

After advices here what I have got:

```
$("th").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var radio1Value; 
        var ifEnoughShips;
        radio1Value = $("input[name='stat']:checked").val(); 

        //sending radiovalue 
        $.ajax({
        url         : "localhost:8126/ship", 
        method      : "get",
        data        : radio1Value

       success: function (response) {
           alert("Success!");
           ifEnoudhShips=response;
        )};
)};
-------------------------
    //REST
public class RestTest{
   @GET
    @Path("abc/{ship}") //here I am not sure because I dont wanna use path
    public int CheckHowMany(@PathParam("ship") Integer ship){
        Checker ch1 = new Checker();
        int res=ch1.CheckNumber(ship);
        return res; //0 if number doesn't exists 1 if it does
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `url : "someurl",` is just a placeholder and will actually contain the correct value. Make sure that you're sending the request to `http://yourdomain.top/ship` since `ship` is the URL that your Java framework listens to (`@Path("/{ship}")`

You need to set the correct method header.
You're sending `method : "post",` while your Java endpoint expects `@Get`. The Java framework will probably not match the POST request with a GET action.

You need to receive a parameter that the Java framework you are using will be able to bind it to. Probably you need to do this:

```
@GET
@Path("/{ship}")
public int Get(string radio1Value) {
    //check in matrix if number from radiovalue exists
}
```

What you need to fix is:

- Use the correct URL
- Use the correct method (use GET or POST in both the request and action)
- Have the action receive a parameter so the value you send is obtainable

*Edit: for the `onclick` part you need to wrap your ajax request into an event using jQuery (since you're using this library). You do this like this:*

```
<button id="execute_on_click">Send request</button>
```

and in your javascript:

```
$("#execute_on_click").click(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "localhost:8126/ship",
        method: "get",
        data: radio1Value

        success: function (response) {
            alert("Success!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes it is a placeholder. But I am not sure if it can be 'http://localhost:8126/ship'?

Comment: Oh so if I am using post method in ajax it should also be POST in REST?

Comment: @BeataKozieł The `yourdomain` should be whatever you're running it on. Locally it will probably be something like `localhost:xxxx` yes. So your example is probably correct. And yes, if you send a POST request, your server code needs to listen to a POST request. The webserver framework uses this protocol to match the request with the right code.

Comment: If you can check edit on my question I would be thankful.

Comment: I am also not sure about: can I use one method to 1. send value from frontend to backend, 2. get this value and use it to check in matrix, 3. send response to frontend, 4. get response from backend?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@PathParam` notation.

```
@GET
@Path("/{ship}")
public int Get(@PathParam("ship") Integer ship){
    //check in matrix if number from radiovalue exists
    return 1; // Return your success int
}
```

After you are done in your function you can return anything you want to the frontend. Also when you are using ajax make sure you are calling your backend via a `GET` method and appending the parameter in the call url.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "someurl",
  type: "get", //send it through get method
  data: radio1Value,

  success: function(response) {
    //Do Something
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    //Do Something to handle error
  }
});
```

Comment: So if I have matrix I can use "ship" and check if this number exists in matrix and if it does I am returning for example 1? This value from parameter will be this value that I have posted from frontend?

Comment: Yes, the ship value in the backend should be the value you sent in the frontend (if it was done right) and you can return any value you want in case of success and return other value in case the element does not exists.

Comment: And it should work after clicking on element or I need to use  browsers address field?

Comment: @BeataKozieł Like it was explained in the other answer, you have to provide a click event function in which you make the ajax request.